# Move Upload File from PHP to CGI

Tags: php, jquery

Im trying to pass post file information to an upload.php file and have that information be sent to a CGI script. There is nothing on the net on how to go about doing this that i can find, iv spent days. I know there are a few people out there that need this, it could help us all that have legacy perl scripts.

**Dataflow:** 
Jquery --> ***Upload.php*** --> index.cgi

**My php:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {  

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "../index.cgi" . $_FILES['file']['name'])){  

            echo "success";  

           exit;  
}  
}  
?>
```

**Post call to CGI example:**

```
foobar.com/index.cgi?act=store&data=$filename
```

Any suggestions would help greatly. Thank you.

Comment: is the CGI Script accessible via HTTP (browser) ?

Comment: Yes it is! it can be reached local and NAT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my understanding, your CGI script is receiving a parameter which is the path of the uploaded script. However you are attempting to pass the uploaded script to your CGI script using a function that is only supposed to move a file from 1 place to another without executing a script.
my suggestion is to do the following

```
<?php
if(isset($_FILES['file'])) {  
    $destination = "new/path/to/".$_FILES['file']['name'];
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $destination)){  

        $data = array();
        //You can add multiple post parameters here
        //$data = array('param1' => 'value1', 'param2' => 'value2');
        $url = "http://url/to/hello.cgi";
        // You can POST a file by prefixing with an @ (for <input type="file"> fields)
        $data['file'] = '@'.$destination;

        $handle = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        $result = curl_exec($handle);
        if($result) {
           echo "success";
        }    
         exit;  
    }  
}  

?>
```

You can execute the cgi script via a CURL POST and pass any params you want

Comment: Ya this totally makes sense im trying it now, ill keep you posted. Thank you so much...

Comment: So now that im understanding your script, my cgi is a bit more complex then just dropping a file in a storage area. The post need to be handled by an ?act=store this starts another script that handles the data.

Comment: is there another way you can think of? thanks again.